# Azure: How to provide limited Access Level to a Container in a Storage Account?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

Me and my team are using Azure Synapse Analytics to ingest data from a REST API to a Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2, in order to create views automatically.

**The only way we could manage to do this in our Workspace was by previously changing the Public Access Level to the Container inside our Storage Account to "Container (anonymous read access for containers and blobs)".**

**Is there any way to avoid doing this, and ***just enable this level of access to specific containers for a limited amount of users / IPs, while keeping it "Private (no anonymous access)"***?**

[Click to Azure Portal view of the Containers inside a certain Storage Account resource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mSMU.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Shared Access Signatures for it. You can find more information in here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview

Comment: In case if you are using any Azure offerings to access the container, you can also leverage RBAC and Managed Identity use case but for generic users access, SAS is the correct way for secured access

Answer (score 0):

I do agree with @Thiago Custodio and @Nandan, we can use SAS Token and URL for limited access to Container in the storage accounts.

**To get SAS token:**

- Firstly, open the storage account, then click on container.
- Then click on your container and then click on Shared Access tokens as below.
- Then you can select what access you want to give access as below. Then Generate the token.

[image]

The token comes as below, now you can send this token to whom you want to give access your container.

[image]

Alternatively, you can also create a private endpoint as below:

- Firstly, click on **Networking**, the click on **Private endpoint connections** and then **(+)** create a end point.

[image]

Now this Container can be accessed from the Virtual Machine integrated with this private endpoint.